# How can I use jQuery.grep() to dynamically filter an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to filter an array of objects to remove some elements from it. I'm trying to use jQuery.grep(), but I don't know if that's the best tool for the job.

Every element on my array of objects has a "type" element, and I need to remove the ones with a particular "type" value. But those values are unknown, since they will be provided by the user.

Here's what I'm stuck with:

```
theNewArray = $.grep(database, function( n ) {
    return ( n.type != /* I don't know what to put here */ );
});
```

I've tried getting all the "type" values in an array, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: If you want to change original array (like object) you shouldn't use `grep` because `grep` doesn't affect original source.

Comment: You will have to find out what type values are invalid or what type values are valid, so you can === check or !== check against those values. Maybe share some more context? How is the code being used in your app?

Comment: Then the question doesn't make any sense. How do you filter something on an unknown criteria? You don't.

Comment: so, save user input in variable and pass it

Comment: @Grundy I'm having problems doing that, I think I haven't found the right syntax to do it.

Comment: @UnaiYécora, can you provide a bit complex sample your code?

Comment: @jlowgren What I mean by unknown is that they will be given by user input. I can have them in an array or something like that, but I don't know how to pass that array.

Comment: @UnaiYécora, if you want check `n.type` in array, you can use _indexOf_, like `return arr.indexOf(n.type) == -1;`

Comment: @Grundy Thanks! I see now that when I tried indexOf I did it totally wrong. I think it's all working now, thank you (:

Comment: @UnaiYécora, if you find solution you can publish it and mark as accepted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in case any other noob came here after me, [@Grundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2881286/grundy) put me on the right path. This is what I ended up using with some context:

```
//Example of the original array of objects that I want to filter
var database = [
  {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName:"Doe",
    type:"Man"
  },
  {
    firstName:"Jane",
    lastName:"Doe",
    type:"Woman"
  },
];

//Here I put the user input in an array (simplified)
var filterArray = [];
$("#settings a.uncheck").each(function(){
    filterArray.push($(this).data( "type" ));
});

//And here I remove the objects in the original array that have the "type" values in the user input
filteredDatabase = $.grep(database, function( n ) {
  return ( filterArray.indexOf(n.type) == -1 );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.filter` to filter out what you don't want, or do want:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Filter out `3`
var result = numbers.filter(function (number) {
  return number !== 3;
});

alert(result);
```

Comment: but seems OP don't know what pass instead `3`